# Using QSharedPointer with new[] yields "Mismatched free() / delete / delete[]" in valgrind

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

I have the following code:

```
QPair<QSharedPointer<unsigned int>, int> someclass::somefunction() {
    int siz = data_size();
    QSharedPointer<unsigned int> buffer(new unsigned int[siz]);

    // Fill the buffer...

    return qMakePair(buffer, siz);
}
```

At some point, the `QSharedPointer` returned by this function will go out of scope and the pointer set in the constructor will be free'd. Using valgrind 3.6.1, I get a "Mismatched free() / delete / delete[]" error. Is there anything wrong with my use of `QSharedPointer` or do I just have to live with this valgrind warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to fix this is to write a custom deleter and pass that to the constructor of `QSharedPointer` like so:

```
template <typename T_>
void do_delete(T_ buf[])
{
    delete[] buf;
}
```

And then

```
QSharedPointer<unsigned int> buffer(new unsigned int[siz], do_delete<unsigned int>);
```

I am not sure whether there is a more elegant solution (which would be nice)

Comment: Qt is simply missing the array counterpart, like boost::shared_array. So is C++11 missing that. So you have the best solution.