# Qt smart pointer equivalent of boost::shared_array?

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers, qsharedpointer

While there exists an equivalent of `boost::shared_ptr` (`QSharedPointer`) I wasn't able to find something that resembles `boost::shared_array`.

Of course I could use something similar to

```
QSharedPointer<const std::vector<T> > shared_vector_ptr(new std::vector<T>(
       reinterpret_cast<T*>(pBuffer),
       reinterpret_cast<T*>(pBuffer+length)
));
```

but I would like to know if there exists a **native** Qt solution which provides `T& operator[](size_t)` and uses `delete[]` instead of `delete`. I'm reluctant to use boost in this project since the target machine couldn't have boost installed and the project gets distributed by source.

Note: I know I can specify a deleter by using `QSharedPointer::QSharedPointer ( T * ptr, Deleter deleter )`, however I dislike approach since the compiler doesn't force you to specify a deleter, which would result in a `new []` allocated block deleted by `delete`.

Comment: There are two excelent posts on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875764/using-qsharedpointer-with-new-yields-mismatched-free-delete-delete-i

Comment: Just for reference: could further downvotes explain themselves? I have no problem with downvotes, but without a comment it's hard to learn what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the nearest is `QScopedArrayPointer`, but of course it's scoped.

It would be little work to subclass `QSharedPointer` to silently add your own hidden `Deleter` that calls `delete[]` (and add an`operator[]`), that way the user wouldn't have to do any thinking, and it's still using Qt native code - you have just wrapped it up neatly.