# When does std::unique_ptr<A> need a special deleter if A has a destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, unique-ptr, delete-operator

If the class `A` in `unique_ptr<A>` it's own destructor, is it necessary to declare a deleter to ensure that the unique pointer uses that destructor? The example I am thinking of is that `A` has a member `mx` of type `user_matrix` (a name I just made up) which needs to call a function `free(...)` to release its memory, one would define

```
~A(){ user_matrix::free(mx); /*etc*/}
```

Since `default_deleter<>` will call `delete`, it is my understanding that that should use `~A()`. However, the example with the opening and closing of directories in Section 5.2, under "Deleters for Associated resources", of the book of Josuttis (The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference) suggests one may need to declare a special deleter to do this, so I am confused.... Is this because, in the given example, the class `DIR` doesn't have a destructor that uses `closedir(...)`?

Comment: The `delete` call that `std::unique_ptr` does will call the destructor.

Comment: Just remember: `delete` when you `new`ed, `delete[]` when you `new[]`ed. Do similarly for other kinds of resources.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875764/using-qsharedpointer-with-new-yields-mismatched-free-delete-delete-i

Comment: One case where you need a special deleter is for APIs that give you a pointer to some resource, and the require that you release the resources through another function call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default deleter of `std::unique_ptr<T>` will call `delete` and the default deleter of `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` will call `delete[]` and those will call the destructors of the objects appropriately.

What may happen is that an operation need be scheduled right before the destruction, either because the destructor is incomplete (or lacking) or because *you* would like to do something more (for example, some logging). *In this case* you need a dedicated deleter to achieve this.

Suppose, for example, that you are given a *handle*, such as `FILE*` (common in C). Those handles often come with a `close` method of some sort and no destructor (because there is none in C).

```
struct FileCloser {
    void operator()(FILE* f) { if (f) { fclose(f); } }
};

UniqueFile = std::unique_ptr<FILE, FileCloser>;
```